# MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 110; timeout -1;

Tags: java, network-programming, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to read messages from my inbox, but I'm keep getting exception **"MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 110; timeout -1;"**

I disabled my AntiVir and Firewall, but doesn't help.

Below is code and console report:

```
public class JavaMailPOP3eMail {

    private String server = null;
    private String user = null;
    private String pass = null;

    public void sendMail() {
        server = "smtp.gmail.com";
        user = "user123@gmail.com";
        pass = "pass123";

        Store store = null;
        Folder folder = null;
        try {
            // get default session
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
            session.setDebug(true);
            // get a pop3 message store, and connect to it
            store = session.getStore("pop3");
            store.connect(server, user, pass);
            // get the default folder
            folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
            if (folder == null) {
                throw new Exception("No default folder");
            }
            // get the inbox
            folder = folder.getFolder("INBOX");
            if (folder == null) {
                throw  new Exception("No POP3 INBOX");
            }
            // open the folder read only
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            // get the messages and print them
            Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                printMail(messages[i]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (folder != null) {
                    folder.close(false);
                }
                if (store != null) {
                    store.close();
                }
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void printMail(Message message) {
        try {
            // get header information
            String from = null;
            from = ((InternetAddress) message.getFrom()[0]).getPersonal();
            // print sender details
            System.out.println("From: " + from);
            // get and print subject
            String subj = message.getSubject();
            System.out.println("Subject: " + subj);
            // get the message itself
            Part messagePart = message;
            Object content = messagePart.getContent();
            if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                messagePart = ((Multipart) content).getBodyPart(0);
                System.out.println("[ Multipart Message ]");
            }
            // get the content type
            String contentType = messagePart.getContentType();
            // if the content is plain text, print it
            System.out.println("Content: " + contentType);
            if (contentType.startsWith("text/plain") || 
                contentType.startsWith("text/html")) {
                InputStream is = messagePart.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is)
                );
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null ) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaMailPOP3eMail mail = new JavaMailPOP3eMail();
        mail.sendMail();
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 110, isSSL false
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 110; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:211)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at example3.JavaMailPOP3eMail.sendMail(JavaMailPOP3eMail.java:43)
    at example3.JavaMailPOP3eMail.main(JavaMailPOP3eMail.java:118)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:312)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:112)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:264)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:207)
```

**EDIT:**

POP is enabled but still doesn't work

[image]

Do you have any other idea what the reason could be ?

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "pop.gmail.com", port 110, isSSL false
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: pop.gmail.com, 110; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:211)  at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:211)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at example3.JavaMailPOP3eMail.sendMail(JavaMailPOP3eMail.java:41)
    at example3.JavaMailPOP3eMail.main(JavaMailPOP3eMail.java:116)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:312)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:112)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:264)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:207)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link from Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665119,1665161), the server should be `pop.gmail.com` (instead of `smtp.gmail.com`) and you have to allow POP access to your account for this to work.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that now, and inform you

Comment: "There was a problem connecting to pop.gmail.com
Server returned error: "Connection timed out: There may be a problem with the settings you added. Please contact your other email provider to verify the correct server name and port." This is a message when I'm trying to configure on gmail account pop3... annoying. Not sure if it is because I'm using name like "randname993.pop3@gmail.com"

Comment: Now I'm getting "Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
Server returned error: "[AUTH] Username and password not accepted."" ... Tell me do you know if yahoo or hotmail has default settings for this with out this configuring?

Comment: If that response comes from Gmail, and the user/pass are correct, then you should "Enable POP" from your Gmail account, under **Settings->Forwarding POP/IMAP**. Something similar is needed for Yahoo accounts, first enabling POP and then connecting to pop.mail.yahoo.com. As for Hotmail, it requires an SSL connection to port 995 of pop3.live.com. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did, but didn't really work... I'll try again tommorow. Thank you for help, I hope it will work.

Comment: Hi @Xerath, I see the screencap and it seems OK. Could you update the code/exception to reflect what happens when you use `pop.gmail.com` instead of `smtp.gmail.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Most people get failed to configured Gmail ID in SMTP .

First you have to do some setting on gmail account :

1) Set less secure app on that account

2) Enable pop from account setting option

3) if it is windows server login gmail account once on the same server.

It will work 100 percent.

Thanks
Sajju